# raise ParseError('Failed to load JSON: {0}.'.format(str(e)))

Tags: python, flask, protocol-buffers

I am making rest API for mobile application using google protocol-buffer i am doing i send a request json in post call and change into protocol-buffer 
what i do recive req in json

```
@app.route('/workerMain', methods=['POST'])
def createWorker():
  assert  request.json is not None,"WorkerPb is invalid"
  return  WorkerHandler.createWorker(builder=request.json)
```

above fuction i used to recive a json then i send json to this to

```
@staticmethod
def createWorker(builder):
    service = WorkerService()
    m_converter = ConvertJSONToPb()
    builder = m_converter.converjsontoPBProper(response=str(builder),instanceType=worker_pb2.WorkerPb())
    return service.create(builder=builder)
```

after that i am convertion json into message `converjsontoPBProper` using this function

```
def converjsontoPBProper(self, response, instanceType):
    finaljson = ""
    finaljson = finaljson+"'"
    for i in response:
        if (i == "'"):
            finaljson += '"'
        else:
            finaljson += i
    finaljson = finaljson+"'"
    return json_format.Parse(text=json.loads(json.dumps(response)), message=instanceType, ignore_unknown_fields=False)
```

in `json_format.Parse` i got an error...

this is my json `{"dbInfo": {"lifeTime": "DELETED"}}`

this error

2019-08-24T09:03:55.557553+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-08-24 09:03:55,554] ERROR in app: Exception on /workerMain [POST]
2019-08-24T09:03:55.557557+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-08-24T09:03:55.557560+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/json_format.py", line 412, in Parse
2019-08-24T09:03:55.557563+00:00 app[web.1]:     js = json.loads(text, object_pairs_hook=_DuplicateChecker)
2019-08-24T09:03:55.557566+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/json/**init**.py", line 361, in loads
2019-08-24T09:03:55.557569+00:00 app[web.1]:     return cls(**kw).decode(s)
2019-08-24T09:03:55.557571+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
2019-08-24T09:03:55.557573+00:00 app[web.1]:     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
2019-08-24T09:03:55.557577+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
2019-08-24T09:03:55.557579+00:00 app[web.1]:     obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
2019-08-24T09:03:55.557581+00:00 app[web.1]: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
2019-08-24T09:03:55.557584+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-08-24T09:03:55.557586+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2019-08-24T09:03:55.557588+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-08-24T09:03:55.557590+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-08-24T09:03:55.557592+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
2019-08-24T09:03:55.557594+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2019-08-24T09:03:55.557596+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
2019-08-24T09:03:55.557598+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2019-08-24T09:03:55.557600+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
2019-08-24T09:03:55.557602+00:00 app[web.1]:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2019-08-24T09:03:55.557604+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
2019-08-24T09:03:55.557606+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise value
2019-08-24T09:03:55.557608+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
2019-08-24T09:03:55.557610+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2019-08-24T09:03:55.557612+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
2019-08-24T09:03:55.557614+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint
2019-08-24T09:03:55.557616+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app.py", line 32, in createWorker
2019-08-24T09:03:55.557618+00:00 app[web.1]:     return  WorkerHandler.createWorker(builder=request.json)
2019-08-24T09:03:55.557620+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/Handlers/workerHandler.py", line 19, in createWorker
2019-08-24T09:03:55.557622+00:00 app[web.1]:     builder = m_converter.converjsontoPBProper(response=str(builder),instanceType=worker_pb2.WorkerPb())
`2019-08-24T09:03:55.557624+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/CommonCode/convertJSONTOPb.py", line 22, in converjsontoPBProper`
`2019-08-24T09:03:55.557627+00:00 app[web.1]:     return json_format.Parse(text=json.loads(json.dumps(response)), message=instanceType, ignore_unknown_fields=False)`
`2019-08-24T09:03:55.557629+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/json_format.py", line 414, in Parse`
`2019-08-24T09:03:55.557631+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise ParseError('Failed to load JSON: {0}.'.format(str(e)))`
`2019-08-24T09:03:55.557634+00:00 app[web.1]: google.protobuf.json_format.ParseError: Failed to load JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1).`

but when i run this from main using two statements it will execute properly

```
reqJson = '{"dbInfo": {"lifeTime": "DELETED"}}'
print(WorkerHandler.createWorker(builder=reqJson))
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this sentence:

```
return json_format.Parse(text=json.loads(json.dumps(response)), message=instanceType, ignore_unknown_fields=False)
```

As said in [docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/google.protobuf.json_format-module) `json_format.Parse` receives properly formatted json text in the `text` paramter.
You don't need the manual fix.

If the `response` param of your method `converjsontoPBProper` is already in json format, then it shouldn't be a problem to do:

```
return json_format.Parse(text=response, message=instanceType, ignore_unknown_fields=False)
```

Instead, if response is a `dict` or an object, it should be enough to do:

```
return json_format.Parse(text=json.dumps(response), message=instanceType, ignore_unknown_fields=False)
```

Comment: now its says `Available Fields(except extensions): ['dbInfo']` but i have that field

Comment: could you paste the full error as a comment? It is interesting to know, which component throw the error, not just the error text.

Comment: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/json_format.py", line 509, in _ConvertFieldValuePair
 [f.json_name for f in message_descriptor.fields]))
2019-08-24T15:56:01.897007+00:00 app[web.1]: google.protobuf.json_format.ParseError: Message type "protobuff.WorkerPb" has no field named "'".
 Available Fields(except extensions): ['dbInfo']

Comment: parser.ConvertMessage(js_dict, message)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/json_format.py", line 466, in ConvertMessage    self._ConvertFieldValuePair(value, message)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/json_format.py", line 577, in _ConvertFieldValuePair
     raise ParseError(str(e))
 google.protobuf.json_format.ParseError: Message type "protobuff.WorkerPb" has no field named "'".
 Available Fields(except extensions): ['dbInfo']

Comment: by the error, it seems the 'dbInfo' field is understood as `'` did you remove the: `finaljson = ""
    finaljson = finaljson+"'"
    for i in response:
        if (i == "'"):
            finaljson += '"'
        else:
            finaljson += i
    finaljson = finaljson+"'"` ?

Comment: Now Error is this => google.protobuf.json_format.ParseError: Message type "protobuff.WorkerPb" has no field named "{".
 Available Fields(except extensions): ['dbInfo']